# Swagger not opening in 2.3.5-p1 magento - "\DateTime" parameter type is invalid

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.5-p1, swagger

I had a fresh installation of magento 2.3.5-p1.

But the swagger is giving error.

I checked git issues where someone has suggested to disable dotmailer modules.

I did, but still the error remains.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue myself, and this is due to the issue in `dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension` as detailed here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28244.
It can be resolved by upgrading that module via

```
composer require dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension:"4.5.1 as 4.4.0"
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Flush all the usual suspects, too: `generated/*`, caches, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with updating the extension due to composer conflicts. I used following to bypass it. Just add it to the `composer.json` file

```
"replace": {
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*"
    }
```

And run

```
composer install
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28244#issuecomment-630077997